# Celery scheduler does not let tasks to run

Tags: django, celeryd, djcelery

Here is excerpt from my settings.py

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
import djcelery
from celery.schedules import crontab
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("app.some.tasks",)

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "send_mail": {
        "task": "app.some.tasks.send_mail",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}
```

When `send_mail` task runs, other tasks can not be run (ignored, not delivered as seen from celeryd log)

```
[2015-08-01 23:39:36,155: INFO/MainProcess] start send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:39:36,185: INFO/MainProcess] finish send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:04,643: INFO/MainProcess] start send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:04,666: INFO/MainProcess] finish send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:06,163: INFO/MainProcess] start send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:06,205: INFO/MainProcess] finish send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:34,657: INFO/MainProcess] start send_mails task.
[2015-08-01 23:40:34,684: INFO/MainProcess] finish send_mails task.
```

But if I execute another task during this 30 seconds interval, then it actually runs.

`send_mail` task

```
@task
def send_mail():
    log.info( u'start send_mails task.' )
    from django.core import management
    management.call_command('send_mail')
    log.info( u'finish send_mails task.' )
```

`send_mail` is command from `mailer` package.

Celeryd is executed as follows

```
celeryd --settings=settings --beat --concurrency=8
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using when you're running "Another task"? Based on what you've shown, there's no reason that wouldn't work.

Comment: Another task can be as simple as `import time; time.sleep(10); log.info('Done')`
The problem is that it is not reproducible locally, only in production.